# regex declare a 'default value' if a tag is empty

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a regular expression which is it returns anything inside the html tag with `id="test"`

ex:

```
<span id="test">Hello World</span>

 <.*?id="pStyle".*?>(.*?)</.*?>
```

it returns **Hello World**

what if a tag is empty it should return too like

```
<span id="test"></span>
```

it should return a default value if a tag is empty. 
I'm currently new on regex is there any regular expression to derrive this empty tags?

Comment: What language / regular expression engine do you use?

Comment: Please stop editing the title. I added a `php` tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you use `preg_match` function. It will always return a string when there is a match. If you want to return null if the tag is empty I think you should add an `if` statement, e.g.

```
$string = '<span id="test">Hello World</span>';
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('%<.*?id="pStyle".*?>(.*?)</.*?>%', $string, $matches) {
    if (empty($matches[1])) {
        return null;
    }
    return $matches[1];
}
```

Also I'd suggest not using this structure: `.*?`. If I would write this RegEx, I would do it that way:

```
<[^>]*id="pStyle"[^>]*>([^<]*)</[^>]*>
```

`[^>]*` means: *Zero or more characters other than `>`.*

Comment: i come up with this it wont do anything 
` $value = 'A';
 $match = array();
    if(preg_match('%<[^>]*id="test2"[^>]*>([^<]*)</[^>]*>%', $html, $match))
    {
        $html = str_replace($match[1],$value,$html);
    }`

Comment: @Darline is your goal to replace the text inside the tag with the `A` string?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after any symbols  `<.*?id="pStyle".*?>(.*?)</.*?>` You should add more than one symbol

```
<(.*)id="pStyle"(.*)>(.*)<\/ (.*)>
```

For me it worked fine